# Prevent empty input in Java's readLine

Tags: java, readline

I would like to prevent the user providing empty input, here's my code

```
private void guessWord(){
    String input = readLine("Your guess: ");
    while(!isValidInput(input)){
        println("Your input is invalid, please try again.");
        input = readLine("Your guess: ");
    }
    char letter = input.charAt(0);
    letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
    if(!(subtituteLetter(letter))){
        println("There are no " + letter + "\'s in the word.");
        life -=1 ;
    }

}
```

I do not want to pass an empty **input** to my **isValidInput**, so how can I prevent readLine from accepting empty input from the user?

Comment: You can't. Just check for empty in `isValidInput()`.

Comment: You can't. You'd... Check for it in your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you while loop with this one:

```
    while(input.isEmpty() || !isValidInput(input)){
        println("Your input is invalid, please try again.");
        input = readLine("Your guess: ");
    }
```

Comment: I'm definitely going for this solution, much more elegant, thank you !

Comment: @user3214407 : Please accept the answer, if you think it has helped you. Read this to understand how accepting the answer works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can simply force user to enter non-empty string in a loop.

```
private void guessWord(){
    String input;
    do{
    input = readLine("Your guess: ");
    }
    while(input.isEmpty());

    while(!isValidInput(input)){
        println("Your input is invalid, please try again.");
        input = readLine("Your guess: ");
    }
    char letter = input.charAt(0);
    letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
    if(!(subtituteLetter(letter))){
        println("There are no " + letter + "\'s in the word.");
        life -=1 ;
    }
}
```